# How to document React redux components?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

How to document React redux components?
Wanted to document React redux components (both presentational and container component)

Comment: What do you mean by "document"? What does this have to do with React or Redux specifically?

Comment: i would like to add documentation for the components

Comment: Haha, okay... what have you tried? What problems did you encounter? What kind of help are you expecting with your problem?

Comment: something similar to ng-docs in angular js

Comment: Did you do a search? Looks like there's a bunch of similar solutions, like [react-docgen](https://github.com/reactjs/react-docgen) or [react-doc-generator](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-doc-generator)

Answer (score 0):

With a typical JavaScript file you can add a comment like below

`// my fancy JS comment`

However, if you try to do this in a React component more than likely the comment will be displayed on the screen.

So to make a fancy React component comment within your component file do something like below,

`{/* my fancy React component documentation */}`